# Android: Widget updating a clock with custom images as numbers

Tags: android, bitmap, widget, clock

What way is most efficient for updating an widget that will be a clock(Timer/Alarm), but for a clock to really works, like a clock it would be needed to update at least twice in a minute (30 sec period or less).

But that can't be effective? Have looked at some of the "threads/topics" here at StackOverFlow but haven't found any information regarding effectiveness.

(Don't own an android device yet, so I can't really test battery draining and cpu)

Comment: When you say "widget", do you mean "widget" (i.e., subclass of `android.view.View`, used in an activity UI), or do you mean "app widget" (i.e., thing that goes on the home screen)?

Comment: Oh, a App Widget that goes on the home screen.

Answer (score 0):

For AppWidget the docs recommend using a service running in background.